# Does git merge add all commits or only last commit?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

So I have been using `git merge` and I don't understand if it adds all commits from merged branch or only the last one

If for example I have a branch `A` and a branch `B`

- `A` has commits: 1 2 5
- `B` has commits: 3 4

so, what would happen if I do `git merge B` in branch `A`?

and what would happen if I do `git merge A` in branch `B`?

What I'm most interested in knowing is what happens when a merge done, are all commits added to current branch or only last one?

Comment: what branch is you merging into? or in other words what branch is current when you "run" merge? that would allow to answer you based on your sample branches/commits.

Comment: also please specify context. are you interested in "what's going on under the hood?", "how my history is changed?"or "what's going on with my work tree(files and code inside)"? each subject would lead to large answer so it's better to pick just one item

Comment: what i'm most intrested in knowing is what happens when a merge done, are all commits added to current branch or only last one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the experiment by your self very easily (Require use of the terminal)

Go to your favorite folder in your command line:

Create an empty repo

```
mkdir test-repo
cd test-repo
git init
```

Add Some content (We will create a file that we will change the content every commit)

```
echo 0 > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m '0'
```

Create branch A

```
git checkout -b A
echo 1 > file.txt; git add file.txt; git commit -m '1'
echo 2 > file.txt; git add file.txt; git commit -m '2'
echo 3 > file.txt; git add file.txt; git commit -m '3'
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

Create Branch B

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b B
echo 4 > file.txt; git add file.txt; git commit -m '4'
echo 5 > file.txt; git add file.txt; git commit -m '5'
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

So in Branch A we have a file with the number 3 and in B a file with the number 5
Lets merger A into B (your current branch is B, remember)

```
git merge B
```

You will see an easy conflict to solve

```
cat file.txt

<<<<<<< HEAD
5
=======
3
>>>>>>> A
```

Fixed and commit:

```
git commit
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

The history will look something like:
[image]

What happens here, You just create a new commit that links A int B, This commit has the conflict resolution between the 2 branches. 
And you still in the branch B

This implies you can remove this commit and come back to the preview state just removing this commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git log
```

So now let's do the other way around, go to the branch A and lets 'merge B into A'.

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

Fix the conflict again that looks pretty similar, but not exactly

```
cat file.txt


<<<<<<< HEAD
3
=======
5
>>>>>>> B
```

Fix the conflict and you should be in the same state but technically not :)
You are in the branch B

```
git commit
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

[image]

So what are the differences? the order of the conflict but the more important, the name of the final branch that you are in.

**So merge create another commit to link the different history of a branch into another one (That's why the commit 0 does not repeat in this example) .**

If you like a clean history, where the final history is something like :
[image]

You should play with `rebase`. But this looks outside the scope of this question.

If you want to create only a single commit from a branch to add into another branch you can `squash` and `rebase`

Git is something that is easier when you learn by doing. CHeck your `git log` often. Learn how to use `git reflog` to gain confidence (is the reason why git is great) and give a chance to `git rebase` commands. Then talk with your team and decide the best workflow.

Answer (score 2):

1. commits are not "moved" into branch.
2. each commit in git stores link to parent commit.
3. merge commits have 2 or more parent commits(they are typically HEAD of appropriate branches)
4. since those commits still keep their parent commits merge operation  virtually "brings all different commits(not existing in current branch before) into current branch". virtually means you will "remove" them from current branch once you remove merge commit(with git reset or git revert)

on the opposite:

a. making rebase would bring all "different" commits by copying them; they will "behave" just like native commits initially created for current branch

b. cherry-pick would make a copy just single commit(last one if you use branch name as an argument); but you can specify a range

Comment: Great answer. I was exactly looking for the word "virtually" to answer all my questions about this. Another proof is: although there are mix of commits from branch `A` and `B`, but if you try to use `git restore --source=HEAD~n file.txt`, You would only see the changes by the *current* branch when `n` increases, not the changes from the merged branch. They are just virtually there in the log.